# Add r_liteprofile permission/ Migrate existing LinkedIn Application to v2 API

Tags: linkedin-api

I need the 'r_liteprofile' permission added to an existing LinkedIn application. The LinkedIn applications for my other environments seemed to be automatically migrated except for this one.

LinkedIn's Migration FAQS state that any application that made a successful v1 API call between Sep 1st 2018 - Dec 17th 2018 will be migrated automatically:

> Does my developer application have access to the LinkedIn v2 API?
>
> All developer applications created on the LinkedIn Developer Portal after January 14, 2019 have access to the LinkedIn v2 API by default. Alternatively, if your developer application has made a successful LinkedIn v1 API request from September 1, 2018 to December 17, 2018, your developer application has immediate access to the v2 API.

Can I add the permission through the console or get access to API v2 if my application missed this window? Or will I need to re-create the application?

I am only using the 'Sign In with LinkedIn' product which needs the `r_liteprofile` permission to work properly. I'd also prefer not to re-create the application as it appears that LinkedIn member ids are returned differently depending on the LinkedIn client id being used.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. Even if LinkedIn sent you here, they can't determine what's on-topic for this site.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. LinkedIn indeed points to StackOverflow for help since they disabled their actual forum. I thought I could try getting more visibility with LinkedIn through here, but looks like no one actually looks at StackOverflow from LinkedIn.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a response from someone at LinkedIn via email who sent me this link to submit help tickets:

*[please refer to below link instead]*

I couldn't find this anywhere on the LinkedIn developer website. So I hope this helps someone.

---

**EDIT:** The previous link is target towards LinkedIn partners. The following link can be used to submit tickets such as mine:

https://linkedin.com/help/linkedin/ask/default-social?source=twitter

Comment: Hey @jalamak, the link you've attached is tailored for LinkedIn Partners, not necessarily developer support. While I've found your ticket and can assist, in the future you can submit a ticket to LinkedIn Help (https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/ask/default-social?source=twitter).

Comment: @ChristopherOu Thank you so much! I've navigated through the LinkedIn website so many times and could not find this link. I'll update my answer.